# dynamic loading of videos in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html5-video

I am using modal box of bootstrap to load videos using videojs.
I need to fetch the video file name from database.

When someone clicks on a link, a `playVideo()` function is called.
What I do is that I populate a div with id videoPlayer and populate it with the video code.
Here is my playVideo function:

```
 function playVideo(id)
  {
   $('video').attr('id','CurrentVideo'+id);
    var videoData=new Array();
   $.getJSON('<?PHP echo base_url();?>admin/content/getVideoDetail/'+id,function(data){
       $.each(data,function(k,v){
           videoData.push(v);
           });
       }).done(function(){

     $("#videoPlayer").html('<video id="CurrentVideo'+id+'" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls width="530" height="264" preload="none"> <source type="video/mp4" src="<?PHP echo base_url()?>content/videos/'+videoData[3]+'"></video>');

    myPlayer=_V_('CurrentVideo'+id);

    $("#videoBox").modal();

    $("#videoBox").on('hide',function(){
     $("#videoPlayer").html('');
    });
       });
   }
```

This works sometimes but is not working very consistently in all browsers. Have i taken a wrong approach? Further, is there any flaw with videojs? should i use some other alternative like flowplayer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I've experienced when using VideoJS:

- Autoplay is a bad idea. If you're hoping that the modal appears and the video to immediately start playing, it will only work correctly in some browsers. Most other browsers have problems (ie. two instances of the audio stream will start playing)
- $("#videoPlayer").html('') you're essentially blowing away the HTML. If you're worried about performance, avoid this. Try re-appropriating existing code/tags. Most devs think that by blowing away the HTML you save memory -- not necessarily true.

And it's not an issue with VideoJS. I've seen a number of different video JS libraries and they don't handle HTML5 videos all too well.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you specified mp4 only. So it will play on Chrome (and maybe on iDevices) but not on Firefox etc.

Can you give more information about on which browser it is working and on which one it isn't?